# pulling a time stamp from a txt file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a txt file log that has user input timestamps. I am writing a code that I can search through the txt file for a word and pull the time stamp associated with that word. The time stamp looks like this

```
+work=2019-08-30|08:41| [IRP] Diagnose
```

I would like to be able to input the word (in this case Diagnose) and the program pull the time stamp from the line and put it in cell A1. My current code can find Diagnose if its alone (ie no timestamp) but for some reason doesn't recognize Diagnose in the timestamp line. Here is the code that i have started. I am looking for recommendation on how to be able to type in Diagnose into my search message box and the result in cell A1 is 2019-08-30|08:41| Thanks for any help you can provide

```
Sub Scan()

Dim stdesfile As String
Dim stdataline As String


stdesfile = Application.GetOpenFilename
Find = InputBox("which word")
Open stdesfile For Input As #1

Do While Not EOF(1)
   Input #1, stdataline
   If stdataline = Find Then
      bFound = True
      Exit Do
   End If
Loop

If bFound = True Then
   MsgBox "Item Found"
Else
  MsgBox "Item not found"
End If

Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: `If stdataline Like "* " & Find Then`

Comment: `If InStr(31, stdataline, find) > 0 Then` (assuming timestamp is always same length)

Comment: thanks for the help, both solutions pull +work=2019-08-30|08:41| [IRP], how do I print just the time stamp to cell a? I thought about using  Range("A1").Value = Mid(stdataline, Find + 7, 23) hoping that would capture just 2019-08-30|08:41| but i keep getting a mismatch. sorry if this is basic still working on my vba skills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code (assuimg the date format is fixed to be 17 characters length):

```
Sub Scan()

Dim stdesfile As String
Dim stdataline As String
Dim idx As Long, dt As String

stdesfile = Application.GetOpenFilename
Find = InputBox("which word")
Open stdesfile For Input As #1

Do While Not EOF(1)
   Input #1, stdataline
   If InStr(1, stdataline, Find) > 0 Then
      idx = InStr(1, stdataline, "=")
      dt = Mid(stdataline, idx + 1, 17)
      bFound = True
      Exit Do
   End If
Loop

If bFound = True Then
   MsgBox "Item Found, date: " + dt
Else
  MsgBox "Item not found"
End If

Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: Won’t that hard code the variables Find and stdataline? I would like it to be fluid so that I can type any word I’m looking for and it retrieves the time stamp which is always the same length and format and then have it print to cell A1

Comment: @user11536789 Here, I've put my modification into your code.

Comment: @userMichał Turczyn code works great by using Range("A1").Value = dt i can send my value to cell A1. I do have a question though i was tinkering with it to understand it better but why does the output change when i do hard code Find = Diagnose? i only ask because as i continue building the code i would like to use Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) to pick a folder with hundreds of logs in them and have it save the diagnose time in column A.